# Is this a bug in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to generate Fibonacci number: F(n+2)=F(n+1)+F(n) using tensorflow. Every time I run my code, it produce different results, very strange. The code is simple and pasted below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(1)
b = tf.Variable(1)
c = tf.Variable(2)
sum=tf.add(a,b) 

as0 = tf.assign(a,b)
as1=tf.assign(b, c) 
as2=tf.assign(c, sum) 

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(10):
    print(sess.run([as2, as1,as0]))
```

Comment: What do you mean it returns different results? I just tried it and it's identical everytime. Doesn't appear to generate your sequence correctly though

Comment: That's a funny one ! I also get different values every time, always incorrect, and always with 2nd and 3rd elements equal, and as2[i]=as1[i]+as1[i-1]. My guess is that you just don't know in what order the graph is executed when you call sess.run(), so the assignments and the sum are performed in a wrong (possibly different each time) order, is that possible as far as you guys know ?

Comment: By the way, the title of the question is too broad, you should change it to something describing your problem better

Comment: Found this question interesting as well, but in essence this is a different question -- to clarify the order in which elements in sess.run() actually get evaluated. One thing is clear though: it's not enough to do tf.assign(), as you also need to run()/eval() that assign in order to actually execute it. So since you are doing them all at once, and some of them depend on each other, the question becomes in what order TF actually executes them in one op. I've seen this asked here before, but don't recall seeing a clear answer beyond "TF figures it out". Would be great to hear from TF guys!

Comment: Sorry, guys. I posted this question a few years ago and then forgot it at all. Thanks for each comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think that @gdelab answer it's not **totally** right. I mean, it's true that solves the problem, but I think that it's not the real reason. Here comes my guess.

I strongly think that you're trying to run that code on a Jupyter Notebook. If that's not true, then probably I'm wrong. Well, supposing that's true:

1. The first time you run the code it gives the right output.[image: First Time]
2. The second time you run the code, it gives another output. [image]
3. But that's because you're not running from scratch. This is, the **kernel is not restarted** and the variables are not erased, so the output changes. If you do *"Restart Kernel"* and then run the code again, the **output is always the same** (The output of the first image)[image]

And now, please, don't tell me that you're not using Jupyter Notebook :)

Answer (score 1):

If some operation can be executed in parallel with another, they probably will be. Thus the order of execution is not the order of the operation you write.

The order of the execution exists only when it's explicitly forced (with [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies)) or when a node must be computed before the computation of another node (when a node is a precondition of another node).

Let's dig into your code:

```
a = tf.Variable(1)
b = tf.Variable(1)
c = tf.Variable(2)
sum=tf.add(a,b)
```

Until now, you just defined 3 variables and an operation.
Please note: you *defined* a node. Nothing has happened.

```
as0 = tf.assign(a,b)
as1=tf.assign(b, c) 
as2=tf.assign(c, sum)
```

Here you *defined* 3 assign operations. There's **no order** between them.
No-one knows what will be executed before and after because there's no cause-effect relationship among them.

The only thing that you can be sure of, is that before assigning the value of `sum` to `c`, sum has to be executed.

Thus, in your graph there's only one arrow that goes from the `sum` node to the `assign(c,sum)` node.

P.S: this is not the recommended way of computing operations like the Fibonacci sequence. Instead, you should use [`tf.scan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan) that has an any parameter `accumulator` that helps you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That's a funny one !

It seems that you just don't know in what order the graph is executed when you call sess.run(), or at least you don't know in which order the computations for each tensor are finished, so the assignments and the sum are performed in a wrong (possibly different each time) order. The following code works fine, by forcing the graph to do things in the right order:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.Variable(1)
b = tf.Variable(1)
c = tf.Variable(2)
sum=tf.add(a,b) 
as0 = tf.assign(a,b)
as1=tf.assign(b, c) 
as2=tf.assign(c, sum) 
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(10):
    sess.run(as0)
    sess.run(as1)
    print(sess.run(as2))
```

This is not very practical, since it is out of the graph. 
You can probavbl use [flow control ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/control_flow_ops#Control_Flow_Operations) to force them to execute in the right order.